# AngularJs - Delete the card that i have clicked inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have an **array** of cards displayed whit an **ng-repeat**. I'm passing the **id** to my function, im using  **$timeout** because i need to delete the card 5 seconds after the click , now the objective is to delete the card that I have clicked. Thanks.

JS

```
$scope.includeCard = function(id){

  $timeout(function(){ 

      console.log(id) 

  },2000)

}
```

My html

```
    <div class="cards"> 

     <div class="" ng-repeat="card in  cards" >

      <div class="card-layout"> 

        <div>Card Example</div>

        <div ng-click="excludeCard(card.id)"></div>

      </div> 

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in js is the function-name $scope.includeCard, in HTML excludeCard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the index of the object that you want to remove and remove it from the array using "splice" function. Try this:

**JS**

```
$scope.includeCard = function(index){

  $timeout(function(){ 

      $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);

  },2000)

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cards"> 

 <div class="" ng-repeat="card in  cards" >

  <div class="card-layout"> 

    <div>Card Example</div>

    <div ng-click="excludeCard($index)"></div>

  </div> 

</div>
```